# how to create an infinite loop FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist rendering a `posterlist` but i want it to loop infinitely so for example if `posterIds` are [1,2,3,4] I want it to loop 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,... etc

```
import { View, FlatList, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import moviesData from "../Fixtures/movieData.json";
import Poster from "./Poster";

const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("screen").width;

const ITEM_SIZE = screenWidth * 0.8;
const SPACING = screenWidth * 0.015;
const FULLSIZE = ITEM_SIZE + SPACING * 2;

const PosterList = ({ posterStyle, onPressPoster }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
      <FlatList
        data={moviesData}
        snapToAlignment="center"
        snapToInterval={FULLSIZE}
        bounces={false}
        decelerationRate="fast"
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Poster
            imageUrl={item.poster}
            style={[
              posterStyle,
              { width: ITEM_SIZE, marginHorizontal: SPACING },
            ]}
            onPressPoster={onPressPoster}
          />
        )}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default PosterList;
```

Comment: The loop should stop somewhere, otherwise, it will hang the browser and the only thing you see will be a frozen screen you can't interact with.